# ideals with fixed norm in a Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Given a general Dedekind domain $R$ is it true that there are at most finitely many prime ideals of $R$ with the same given norm? By "norm" I mean the index of the ideal in $R$, assumed to be finite.

Comment: I've done Dedekind domains many years ago, but this should be the proof, if I remember correctly... First, in Dedekind domain $R$, take an ideal $I$ with given norm $n=N(I)\in\mathbb Z\subset R$. The principal ideal $nR$ is therefore contained in $I$, or in "division" terminology, $I$ divides $nR$. (Each ideal divides its norm.) Thus (due to unique factorisation of ideals in $R$), $I$ can only be one of (finitely many) divisors of $nR$.

Comment: Of course that works, but only for Dedekind domains of characteristic zero. The tricky part seems to be positive characteristic, where $nR$ could be the zero ideal.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373569

Comment: @StinkingBishop I don't know if it pings you when I answer since you set a bounty, but since you're obviously interested I wanted to make sure you saw my answer below.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I was checking this question anyways, I couldn't miss it! Thanks for your answer, will take me a bit of time to digest it though.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Absolutely! Take your time. It's a result I learned  by leisurely exploring algebra textbooks many years ago--it's stuck with me as a surprisingly general, powerful result. Happy reading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One has the following general result:

> **Theorem (Gilmer--Heinzer):** Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. Then, there exists only finitely many ideals $I$ of $R$ such that $|R/I|\leqslant n$ for any
> natural number $n$.

For a proof one can see [1]. For a more leisurely discussion see [2, Pg. 15].

[1] Gilmer, R. and Heinzer, W., 1992. *Products of commutative rings and zero-dimensionality*. Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 331(2), pp.663-680.

[2] Anderson, D.F. and Dobbs, D. eds., 1995. *Zero-dimensional commutative rings* (Vol. 171). CRC Press.