# Show that there can be only finitely many localizations of a Noetherian ring such that |A/Pi| <= n.

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring, and let $n$ be a fixed natural number. Show that there are only finitely many primes $P$ of $A$ such that the cardinality of $A/P \leq n$.

Prime ideals in noetherian rings have a property: if we have one prime ideal strictly in between two prime ideals, then we have infinitely many primes between them.
[Noetherian rings and prime ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334373/noetherian-rings-and-prime-ideals)

Is this useful here?
I don't know how to start, kindly help.

Comment: I don't see any reason to think that fact would be helpful.  I would do this by mapping $A$ to the product of all those quotients and then showing the image of $A$ in the product is generated by idempotents and thus zero-dimensional.  Maybe there is a more direct argument though.

Comment: can you elaborate more or maybe write it as an answer?

Comment: In fact, this is true not just for prime ideals of $A$, but all ideals of $A$. See the beautiful answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3796268/73817