# Number of ideals in a ring of algebraic integers with bounded norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ to be the ring
of algebraic integers.
I was wondering if there is some sort of asymptotic formula or bound for
say number of ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$, with norm less than $X$.

I would also appreciate any reference too! Thank you!

Comment: This is answered here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92426/how-many-elements-in-a-number-field-of-a-given-norm by Bruno with the equation $\sum_{n \le N} a_n \sim C_K N$