# Proof Cassinis identity with induction and Fibonacci sequence

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

Let $p_1,p_2,p_3,...$ be the numbers from the Fibonacci sequence $(1,1,2,3,5,...)$

Proof Cassini's identity:

$p^2_{n+1}-p_n*p_{n+2}=(-1)^n$, where n is a natural number

I have tried to prove it by induction.

First I let $n=1$.

$1^2-1*2=(-1)^1\Rightarrow 1-2=-1\Rightarrow-1=-1$

As it's true for $n=1$ it must be true for all $n$ if it's true for $n+1$. So what I have to proof is that

$p^2_{n+2}-p_{n+1}p_{n+3}=(-1)^{n+1}$

I am uncertain how to proceed from here and if I'm correct so far.

Comment: To me, the clearest proof is the one that uses matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities#Proof_by_matrix_theory.

Comment: You can find several posts about Cassini's identity on this site: 
[Fibonacci identity: $f_{n-1}f_{n+1} - f_{n}^2 = (-1)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20948),
[Fibonacci number identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1420281), 
[Induction proof on Fibonacci sequence: $F(n-1) \cdot F(n+1) - F(n)^2 = (-1)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/523925), etc.

Comment: Thank you for the list. @MartinSleziak do you know if $F_{k-1}=F_{k+1}-F_k$ holds for all sequences or if it's a special property of Fibonacci numbers?

Answer (score 1):

$$p_{n+2}^2-p_{n+1}p_{n+3}=p_{n+2}(p_{n}+p_{n+1})-p_{n+1}(p_{n+1}+p_{n+2})=\cdots.$$

Comment: Can you make another step in between the equation sign? I do not quite see how you arrive there.

Also I am not certain I understand exactly how to end the proof by induction. Do I simple need to rewrite the left side into the right side?

Answer (score 1):

we denote the sequence by $F_{k}$ and we assume that the identity for $n=k$
 $$F_{k+1}F_{k-1}-F_k^2=(-1)^{k+1}$$
plugging $$F_{k-1}=F_{k+1}-F_k$$ in the given equation then we have
$$F_{k+1}(F_{k+1}-F_k)-F_k^2=(-1)^{k+1}$$
$$F_{k+1}^2-F_{k+1}F_k-F_k^2=(-1)^{k+1}$$
$$F_{k+1}^2-F_k(F_{k+1}+F_k)=(-1)^{k+1}$$
$$F_{k+1}^2-F_kF_{k+2}=(-1)^{k+1}$$
and this is the identitiy for $n=k+1$

Comment: How do you arrive to $F^2_{n+1}-F_nF_{n+2}=F_{k+1}F_{k-1}-F_k^2$. I seem to be having problems rewriting the expressions involving the "sub n+1" terms. 

Forexample: Why does $F_{k+1}(F_{k+1}-F_k)=F_{k+1}F_{k-1}$

Comment: multiplying by $(-1)$

Comment: $$F_{k-1}=F_{k+1}-F_k$$ by definition

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you. Do you recall what "field" or what I could google to understand this concept and the rules of calculation better?