# Given $F_m$ be the $m^\text{th}$ number in the Fibonacci sequence. Prove that for all natural $n$, $|F_n^2 + F_nF_{n + 1} - F_{n + 1}^2| = 1$.

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

> Given $F_m$ be the $m^\text{th}$ number in the Fibonacci sequence. Prove that for all natural $n$, $$\large |F_n^2 + F_nF_{n + 1} - F_{n + 1}^2| = 1$$

(When I'm bored, I do random stuff.)

There has been a solution below if you want to check out. And I would be appreciated if there are other solutions.

Comment: An interesting related observation is that for positive integers $m,n$ the equation $|m^2+mn-n^2|=1$ implies that $m$ and $n$ are consecutive Fibonacci numbers. This played a key role in an IMO problem in '81. Essentially Vieta jumping.

Comment: $|F_n(F_n+F_{n+1})-F_{n+1}^2|=|F_nF_{n+2}-F_{n+1}^2|=1$ from [Cassini's Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420281/fibonacci-number-identity).

Comment: For a slightly more advanced connection you should observe that the field norm $N$ of $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ reads
$$N(m+n\frac{1+\sqrt5}2)=(m+n\frac{1+\sqrt5}2)(m+n\frac{1-\sqrt5}2)=m^2+mn-n^2.$$ Therefore the equation I described amounts to find the units of the ring of algebraic integers in $K$. This can also be viewed as solving a Pell equation. Anyway $-1$ and $(1+\sqrt5)/2$ generate that group of units and the claim follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, $$F_1^2 + F_1F_2 - F_2^2 = 1^2 - 1 \cdot 1 + 1^2 = 1$$

Assuming that the above statement is correct with $n = p \in \mathbb Z^+$. We have that $$F_{p + 1}^2 + F_{p + 1}F_{p + 2} - F_{p + 2}^2 = F_{p + 1}^2 + F_{p + 1}(F_p+ F_{p + 1}) - (F_p + F_{p + 1})^2$$

$$ = -F_p^2 - F_pF_{p + 1} + F_{p + 1}^2$$

$$ \implies |F_{p + 1}^2 + F_{p + 1}F_{p + 2} - F_{p + 2}^2| = |F_{p + 1}^2 + F_{p + 1}F_{p + 2} - F_{p + 2}^2| = 1$$

Using mathematical induction, for all natural $n$, $|F_n^2 + F_nF_{n + 1} - F_{n + 1}^2| = 1$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
d_n
&=F_n^2 + F_nF_{n + 1} - F_{n + 1}^2\\
&=F_n^2 + F_n(F_n+F_{n - 1}) - (F_n+F_{n - 1})^2\\
&=F_n^2 + F_n^2+F_nF_{n - 1} - (F_n^2+F_{n - 1}^2+2F_nF_{n - 1})\\
&=F_n^2 -F_nF_{n - 1} - F_{n - 1}^2\\
&=-(F_{n - 1}^2+F_nF_{n - 1}-F_n^2)\\
&=-d_{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

$d_1
=F_1^2 + F_1F_{2} - F_2^2
=1+2-4
=-1
$.

Therefore
$d_n = (-1)^n$.